# Tracking every tensor variable's changing while training

Tags: logging, tensorflow, tracking

Is it possible to track a variable's value while training and test?
I'm going to log every step's tensor value and make some program see
it.

But before doing this: is it possible using tensorflow's summary
function?  If possible, using only tensorboard and web site, then it
wouldn't give me detail info and I couldn't get intuition.

Comment: Improve grammar, remove "TIA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Tensorboard and summary ops. Take a look at the examples here: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/

Hope that helps!